# Should I use `this` within a class?

Tags: c++, class, this

Within a member function of a class in C++, does it make a difference, if I use `this->dataMember` or just  `dataMember`? What is considered better style? Is there any performance difference?

(I am not talking about the case where a local variable has the same name as the data member, in which case you must, to my knowledge, use `this->` to distinguish between them.)

Answer (score 55):

As a general rule, it's a question of local conventions.  Most of the
places I've seen do not use `this->` except when necessary, and that's
the convention I prefer as well, but I've heard of people who prefer to
use it systematically.

There are two cases when it is necessary.  The first is if you've hidden
the name with the same name in local scope; if e.g. you have a member
named `toto`, and you also named your function argument `toto`.  Many
coding conventions mark either the member or argments to avoid this 
case, e.g. all member names start with `my` or `m_`, or a parameter name
will start with `the`.

The other case is that `this->` can be used in a template to make a name
dependent.  This is relevant if a template class inherits from a
dependent type, and you want to access a member of the base, e.g.:

```
template <typename T>
class Toto : public T
{
public:
    int f()
    {
        return this->g();
    }
};
```

Without the `this->` here, `g()` would be a non-dependent name, and the
compiler would look it up in the context of the template definition,
without taking the base class into consideration.

Comment: This is a great answer, I hadn't considered the template case.

Answer (score 17):

I always use `this` when calling member *functions*.

1. It turns the function name into a dependent name so that base class member functions are found within a class template.
2. It suppresses argument-dependent lookup.  ADL has its advantages, but it can lead to surprising behavior, and I like it if it's not getting in my way.
3. It has no real disadvantages, and so I use it for all member function calls for consistency reasons.
4. I program in Python a lot where an explicit `self` is mandatory, so it's not a real burden for me.

But for data members I use it only when necessary because there is no ADL taking place.  To answer your specific questions:

> Within a member function of a class in C++, does it make a difference, if I use this->dataMember or just dataMember?

Yes, if this is within a class template.  Then `dataMember` is considered a non-dependent name, which can lead to semantic differences.  For example:

```
#include <iostream>

int i = 1;

struct R {
  int i;
  R(): i(2) { }
};

template<typename T>
struct S: T {
  void f() {
    std::cout << i << ' '     // selects ::i
              << this->i      // selects R::i
              << std::endl;
  }
};

int main() {
  S<R>().f();
}
```

> What is considered better style?

I don't think that there is a strong opinion within the community about this.  Use either style, but be consistent.

> Is there any performance difference?

I'm pretty sure there isn't.

Answer (score 9):

it's simply redundant to use `this->` to call members, unless you want to semantically distinguish between locals and members quickly.
a lot of people use the `m_` prefix for class members, to avoid writing `this->` all the time.

Answer (score 9):

This is a matter of style.  Some people like the extra `this->` to make it more obvious that you are accessing a class member.  But if you feel it's obvious enough without it, there will be no difference in the generated code or performance.

(Besides the case you mentioned with overlapping scopes, `this->` can also be mandatory in a template when trying to name a member of a type-dependent base class.)

Answer (score 3):

use this when you have a hidden/private member =) in any other case it does not make a difference =)

from the IBM information center i quote the following

> Unless a class member name is hidden, using the class member name is
>   equivalent to using  the class member name with the this pointer and
>   the class member access operator (->).

Answer (score 1):

using "this->" is better (you are sure it's the members) but it's doesn't make a difference

Answer (score 1):

If a template function makes a call to a member function such that the call does not depend on any template parameters, `this->` can be used to help the compiler as an alternative to `MyUtopicClass<int, double, double>::vin()`.

Comment: Careful: if `vin` is a virtual function, then `this->vin()` and `MyUtopicClass<int, double, double>::vin()` are different.