# MIL vs. fieldname vs. this->fieldname

Tags: c++

In C++, there are a couple ways to make constructors - with the Member Initialization List (MIL), with `this->field1 = 1`, or by just doing `field1 = 1`.

Which is the best way to construct a structure, when is it ideal to use these three methods??

I'm most curious about the difference between `this->field1` and `field1`, do they not refer to the same field in a structure?

Comment: MIL always when it's possible. The latter two are equivalent (except for some specific template  contexts)

Comment: The member intializer list does not do the same thing as the other two methods, but if you limit this question to the two other cases, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/993352/when-should-i-make-explicit-use-of-the-this-pointer) is a duplicate.

Comment: Possible dupes: [Why should I prefer to use member initialization list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926752/why-should-i-prefer-to-use-member-initialization-list), [Should I use `this` within a class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9590820/should-i-use-this-within-a-class)

Comment: There does seem to be two separate questions here (which might be not obvious to someone asking this), so I've added a second question to the "potential duplicate" list.